# Sharing PDF file form WebView Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

hi i have tried with this code but didn't worked

```
var pdfLoc = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.triestetrasporti.it/download.php?f=c113b7c217cdffd07ee371678a8f8699&target=0.pdf")!)

var oggetti  = [pdfLoc]
        let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: oggetti, applicationActivities: nil)
```

Error : Cannot find an initializer for type 'UIActivityViewController' that accepts an argument list of type '(activityItems: [NSData?], applicationActivities: nil)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIActivityViewController` expects an array of NSData to be initialized, but your `oggetti` variable is an array of *Optional* NSData.

My guess is you should unwrap it:

```
var oggetti = [pdfLoc!]
```

[See Apple documentation about this here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActivityViewController/initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:)